# Substring excluding hyperlinks

Tags: php, substr

This is obvious, but if you perform a substr on a $content field, the output of characters is going to depend on any href attributes in the content. Is there a simply way to perform the substr while exclusing the href tags?

```
$excerpt = substr( $content, 0, 155 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use http://php.net/strip_tags before you do the substr.

Or, if you need more control as to what to remove from $content, use http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php.

Comment: Ok. I don't see that in the question though.